# Does the Baidu search spider understand Javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, seo, search-engine-bots

More specifically, if/how well does the Baidu search crawler index -

- Content delivered via AJAX
- History API (pushState())

I've looked through their documentation and [webmaster tools](http://zhanzhang.baidu.com) but can't find a 'View as Baidu bot' tool (like Google & Bing have) that shows a preview of how your site is indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately.

Here is a [Badui SEO Guide](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/f576c31d650e52ea5518983f.html)

Page 9

> Use text instead of flash, images, Javascript, etc. to display important content...

Comment: Does it still holds nowadays?

Comment: yeah looks like it still, take a look at mipengine.org its their Google AMP clone.